# Найти подстроку, находящеюся между двумя символами в Python

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть строка:

```
b'<inbox@temp.com>'
```

Мне нужно получить подстроку, которая находится между < и >:

```
inbox@temp.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = input_str[input_str.find('<'):input_str.rfind('>')]
```